# How to set submake global variable with shell loop variable in parent

Tags: makefile

I am a novice make user and am unable to pass a shell loop variable to my submake invocation and would like your help understanding how to do so. In the makefile, I need the submake's global variable changed with each loop run of the parent so that I can different actions based on the loop count.

Tried many different things such as $(eval regress_loop = $$shell_loop), export regress_loop = $$shell_loop and also $$variable, $(variable), $($(variable)) in the make call all with no success.

Edited to add the relevant lines of the makefile (not direct paste of code):

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

regress_loop ?= 2

run:
    echo "Regress Loop: $(regress_loop)"
ifeq ($(regress_loop), 1)
    <cmd1> # run one flavor of command
else
    <cmd2> # run another flavor of command
endif 

regress:
   shell_loop=1; while [ $$shell_loop -lt 3 ]; do \
      echo "Testcase $$shell_loop ..."; \
       $(MAKE) -e regress_loop=$$shell_loop run > regress.$${shell_loop}.log; \
       shell_loop=`echo $$shell_loop+1 | bc`; \
   done
```

Then I call from command prompt:
make regress

Comment: Pro tip: `eval` is an extremely advanced operation.  People wrote massively sophisticated makefiles for 30 years without it.  It's highly unlikely you'll need it for your makefile, so just take it out of your toolbox altogether (for now).

Comment: Your makefile works fine if you correct the typographical error `ifeq($(regressloop), 1)` -> `ifeq ($(regress_loop), 1)`. Note space after `ifeq`

Comment: Sorry, I had the space in my code. I forgot to type it here. Anyway, it is not working. I always execute the elsif clause of the run target no matter what I put in the submake call. I put an echo on regressloop in the run target and it always prints 2.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution in `make` is generally to use explicit dependencies, and let `make` itself figure out how many times it needs to do something.

For example;

```
numbers := 1 2
.PHONY: regress
regress: $(patsubst %,regress.%.log,$(numbers))
regress.1.log:
    <cmd1> >$@
regress.2.log:
    <cmd2> >$@
```

One way this could perhaps be generalized is to define one variable for each target. `make` doesn't have arrays, so this is a bit clunky, but it works:

```
numbers := 1 2
run_1 := <cmd1>
run_2 := <cmd2>
.PHONY: regress
regress: $(patsubst %,regress.%.log,$(numbers))
regress.%.log:
    $(run_$*) >$@
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. But what if  I need to run this regression a 100 or a 1000 times? Is it possible to put it in a loop or do I have to copy and paste these so many times in the file? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the command for each log file is unique, you'll have to specify it *somehow.* It's hard to generalize from just two examples but in broad terms, you want to avoid repeating any code (see [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).